# Does not implement inherited abstract member error, but base class does implement

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

Getting a compile error in C# saying that my child class does not implement an inherited abstract data member.

Structure is essentially this:

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    public abstract int MyMethod();
}

public abstract class GeneralTransaction : Transaction
{
    public override int MyMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SpecificTransaction : GeneralTransaction
{
}
```

It is saying that SpecificTransaction is not implementing MyMethod, but why does it have to? The GeneralTransaction class implements it and the SpecificTransaction class inherits from that class?

Comment: That compiles perfectly fine. I suspect something changed when simplifying the code to post it here. Double-check the real code, and try to provide a closer-to-real example of the code so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid that youre structure is more complicated than this. This example works just fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tr = new SpecificTransaction();
        Console.WriteLine(tr.MyMethod()); //shows 1
    }
}

public abstract class Transaction
{
    public abstract int MyMethod();
}

public abstract class GeneralTransaction : Transaction
{
    public override int MyMethod()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SpecificTransaction : GeneralTransaction
{
}
```

Comment: I was missing the "override" in my actual implementation, doh! Thank you!